# Error in generating schema with data for SQL Server 2005 from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Save or publish script wizard in my SQL 2008 R2 gave following error when i tried to generate schema and data for SQL Server version 2005.

Error message:

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoException: Column RemainingTime in object ExamAttempt contains type Time, which is not supported in the target server version, SQL Server 2005. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

Is there any alternative for for type Time in SQL 2005???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use datetimes to store each unit. Doing so ensures youll be able to use all native datetime functions in future to search or manipulate this data. You'll also be able to easily cast forward to the discrete data types in future, should you choose to upgrade the 2005 db.

In example below see how to afford some data type integrity using check constraints.

```
declare @time time = '10:30',
        @date date = '01/01/2001';

select  [theTime] = cast(@time as datetime),
        [theDate] = cast(@date as datetime),
        [theDateTime] = cast(@time as datetime) + cast(@date as datetime);

declare @t table (theDate datetime check(dateAdd(dd,datediff(dd,0,theDate),0) = theDate), theTime datetime check(datediff(dd,0,theTime) = 0))

-- succeeds, since you didnt supply date in the time only column
insert into @t  
    values(cast('01/01/2001' as datetime), cast('10:30' as datetime));

-- fails, since you passed date with the expected time only value
insert into @t
    values(cast('01/01/2001' as datetime), cast('01/01/2001 10:30' as datetime));

-- fails, since you passed time with expected date only value
insert into @t
    values(cast('01/01/2001 10:30' as datetime), cast('10:30' as datetime));
```